# How to edit label

Tags: ios, soap, uilabel

When I send some values to web service my labels display some fields of web service.

StationIDLabel show me station ID from web service like 12/345.But I want to display like 12345

didStartElement

```
if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"StationID"] ) {
    if (!retornoSOAP) {
        retornoSOAP = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
    teveRetorno = YES;
  }
```

didEndElement

```
  if (

    [elementName isEqualToString:@"StationID"] ) {

    StationIDLabel.text = retornoSOAP;
    retornoSOAP = nil;
    teveRetorno = NO;

 }

 }
```

Comment: so you want to remove the slash "/" ?

Comment: that means you want to remove / right?

Comment: Yes I want remove slash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
    retornoSOAP = [retornoSOAP stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@""];
    //add above line

    StationIDLabel.text = retornoSOAP;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"StationID"] ) {
    retornoSOAP = [retornoSOAP replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, retornoSOAP.length)]; 
    StationIDLabel.text = retornoSOAP;
    retornoSOAP = nil;
    teveRetorno = NO;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
NSString *myString = @"123/45";
    myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"My String %@", myString);
```

Comment: the middle line is the main code. I think you have already understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
NSString *stringWithoutUnWantedChar = [myString 
   stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@""];
```

Replace Each Char that you do not want.and this code will remove all unwanted character but not the numbers form your string

```
NSString *originalString = @"(123) 123/123 abc";
    NSMutableString *strippedString = [NSMutableString 
            stringWithCapacity:originalString.length];

    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:originalString];
    NSCharacterSet *numbers = [NSCharacterSet 
            characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];

    while ([scanner isAtEnd] == NO) {
      NSString *buffer;
      if ([scanner scanCharactersFromSet:numbers intoString:&buffer]) {
        [strippedString appendString:buffer];

      } else {
        [scanner setScanLocation:([scanner scanLocation] + 1)];
      }
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", strippedString); // "123123123"
```